# How to display multi-value field containing unique field values in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Ok so I'm coming from a Splunk background and I'm trying to replicate a search using Kibana.

The important part of the splunk query displays unique values for a given field by way of creating a multi-value field.

Splunk aggregation: | stats values(field1) as FieldValues, count as EventCount by field2

This results in a data table that gives a count (EventCount) of unique values of field2 and also creates a multi-value field with a list of the unique values of field1 for each row.

Is this possible using Kibana visualizations?  I am not interested in the unique count, or splitting this up into multiple tables.  I have scoured the forums but have yet to find a way to do this.

Comment: Just to add this this: I have managed to get close to what I want by using the "Top Hit" aggregation, however the same field values are being displayed multiple times.  Why?

I'm looking to see each unique field value listed only once instead of what I'm seeing: "field1, field2, field1, field3, field2, field1"

Comment: just to be sure I got your problem right, say that your field1 stores first names and field2 stores last names, do you expect a table with something like `Alice 5; Bob 12`, when there are 5 unique last names associated with all the Alices, and 12 unique last names for Bobs?

Comment: Thanks for responding...I don't need the unique counts of the values, but only the unique values themselves without them being repeated.  I'm only looking for the unique values of field1 while field2 with be broken up into buckets.

Comment: I see, I'm not aware of a way to achieve that. Curious to read the answer as well :)

Comment: @JeffreyWilk did you get anywhere with this. I am in a similar position coming from splunk. tks

Answer (score 0):

Go into dashboards/visualise ->
create visualise ->
choose datatable ->
choose source ->
buckets ->
slit by table/rows ->
aggregation = terms
select field ->
Update and that should work.

[image]

Comment: thanks but that doesn't really give me what I'm looking for.  I need a sub-aggregation...or the unique values for each bucket